# How to modify java class object in JNI layer

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I need to change/assign values of java class object in JNI layer. I am new to Java and JNI. Below are the codes that I have written.

**JNI_Test.java**

```
public class JNI_Test {
    enum Gender {
        MALE,
        FEMALE;
    }

    class StudentDetails {
        int rollNum;
        String studentName;
        Gender gender;
    }

    class Students {
        int studentsCount;
        StudentDetails stDetails;
    }

    public native int getStudentDetails(Students obj);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("student");
    }
}
```

In the below JNI layer i need to assign/modify the value of `Students obj`

**JNI_Test.c**

```
#include "JNI_Test.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNI_1Test_getStudentDetails (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject student)
{
    jint retVal = 0;

    /** Here I need to assign/modify value to the 'jobject student' java object 
        like student.studentsCount = 10; ...*/

    return retVal;
}
```

Someone please help me i don't know what to do anymore.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

JNI is terribly complicated.  I would try using JNA if that is an option.  With straight JNI, you have to do something like this.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNI_1Test_getStudentDetails (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject student)
{
    jint retVal = 0;
    jclass thisClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
    jfieldID fidStudentCount = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, thisClass, "studentsCount", "I");
    jint number = 10;
    (*env)->SetIntField(env, student, fidStudentCount, number);
    return retVal;
}
```

With JNI, you have to be very careful with strings for instance or you can have memory leaks.  For instance, you have to pair calls to GetStringUTFChars with ReleaseStringUTFChars.

See also [this link](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html).

Comment: very good example. I a new to jni, I want to know is it a habbit to return jint rather void for checking whether return value is NULL for exception check?